# array crashing at index which is in bounds?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

Can anyone help me out with explaining why my array is crashing.

Basically I have two buttons which change the image in the imageView.

h:

```
@interface CaseStudySecondPageViewController : UIViewController
{
    //scroller and back and forward buttons for custom control.
    __weak IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
    __weak IBOutlet UIButton *back;
    __weak IBOutlet UIButton *forward;

    //app delegate to return the selected case study from the other controller.
    AppDelegate *del;

    //variables for displaying the case studies
    NSArray *myImageArray;
    NSInteger localSelctorInt;
}

//setup a IBOutlet to allow the image to be changed.
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *logoImage;

@end
```

m:

update method:

```
-(void)Updater
{

[logoImage setImage:[myImageArray objectAtIndex:localSelctorInt]];

}
```

previous and next buttons:

```
 //returns to previous image if back button is clicked.
-(void) back:(id)sender
{
    if (localSelctorInt > 0)
    {
        localSelctorInt--;
    }
    else
    {
        localSelctorInt = 0;
    }
    [self Updater];
}

//returns to next image if forward button is clicked. increase 7 if array size changes.
//1 removed from int as in starts at 1 and array starts at 0.
-(void) forward:(id)sender
{
    if (localSelctorInt < 7)
    {
        localSelctorInt++;
    }
    else
    {
        localSelctorInt = 7;
    }
    [self Updater];
}
```

and finally my image array is declared in:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //setup the delegate to allow access to the int which was modified on the page before.
    del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //assign a local variable to the int from the previous page.
    localSelctorInt = *(del.selectorInt);

    //create back and forward buttons as UIButtons first.
    [back addTarget:self action:@selector(back: ) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [forward addTarget:self action:@selector(forward:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //pass the ui buttons into ui bar items.
    UIBarButtonItem *UIBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:back];
    UIBarButtonItem *UIForward = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:forward];

    //add these to an array (notice item"s").
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:UIForward, UIBack, nil];

    //initialize the array with all of the images for the case studies logos.
    myImageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_Arm.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_Fife"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_Findel.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_BirkBeck.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_NHS_Dudley.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_NHS_Kensignton.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_Yorkshire_Water.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_Uni_Hertfordshire.png"],
            nil];

    //call update method once to load the first image selected from the previous page.
    [self Updater];
}
```

now my app crashes when it trys to index the 4th image (3rd in the array):

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 ..
>   2]'

It's probably something really simple, but id appreciate your help, cheers.

Comment: you can remove the 'else' blocks in your back and forward methods

Comment: Make sure every png file is existed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at your exception, it says that your array contains 3 objects only ( `... bounds [0..2] ...` ). So, my guess is that your fourth image doesn't exist ... Check spelling of `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_BirkBeck.png"]`. Does this image really exist? It returns `nil`, list of objects is `nil` terminated, so, your array does contain 3 images only instead of 8 images.

*Side Note:* Don't use magic constants like `localSelctorInt < 7`. Always rely on real number of elements in array (`_myImageArray.count`). It's a way to hell ...

*2nd Side Note:* Don't declare ivars without underscore prefix. Do use something like this `_myImageArray` for ivar name.

Comment: Not exactly. I think the array will still contains 8 objects but since the third one is nil the inner implementation treats it as the end of the array

Comment: Maybe you're right, but it's irrelevant how `NSArray` treats it internally. For `NSArray` user, it does contain 3 images in this case.

Comment: I agree with @RobertVojta I have had a simpler issue in the past where an object was returning nil and because it was nil terminated `NSArray` it was not adding anything after this.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, all the images exist as they dispplay on the previous page, for example the first page where app.selectorInt is set has all the images on it. The the second page (this view shown here) will only have the image selected on it. It displays this image on the page but just crashes the app?

Comment: So, there's something wrong elsewhere, but your array doesn't contain 8 images, but just 3. Look at exception.

Comment: BTW how do we know that the array in the exception is the same one of the images ? do you have any other arrays involved ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess its due to not allocating the array

```
myImageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_Arm.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_Fife.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_Findel.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_BirkBeck.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_NHS_Dudley.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_NHS_Kensignton.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_Yorkshire_Water.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_Uni_Hertfordshire.png"],
        nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it still crashes.

Comment: does your apps works fine when it tries to index first or second ?